# Django: Parse JSON in template using Javascript array

Tags: javascript, django, parsing

In my template I pass parameters in array:
`technicCategories` is array of `json_serializer.serialize`
So I can't to make something like this: `var technicCategories = '{{ technicCategories|escapejs }}';` because it is array and I tried and it gives me error: "`JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "u"`", my array looks like: `var technicCategories = '[u\u0027[{\u0022model\u0022: \u0022automarket.technicandallf...`. So i decided to do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < {{ index }}; i++){
            var technicCategories = '{{ technicCategories.i|escapejs }}';
            technicCategories = JSON.parse(technicCategories);
            console.log(technicCategories);
    }
```

but there is a problem: `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF`. But if I make this: `var technicCategories = '{{ technicCategories.0|escapejs }}';` all works fine but gives me only object at index 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't find solution. So I decided to remind my way to do this

Answer (score 0):

What is in technicCategories ? And why are you only trying to put inside a variable only first value from list?

Try this `var technicCategories = '{{ technicCategories|safe }}';`

It should do the trick, and in technicCategories variable, there will be a array of your elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the whole data, instead of just the elements of the list. So create a list with all the elements you want to serialize, and then serialize the list.

If that is not possible for some reason, you can iterate through the list in the template.

```
var technicCategories = '[{% for element in technicCategories %}{{element|safe}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}]';
```

But I really recommend the first approach.